# Autoincrement primary key in CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, primary-key, auto-increment, ctas

I created table using a complicated select query via `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT...`. How can I add an autoincrement primary key in this query?

For example:

```
create table `user_mv` select `user`.`firstname` as 
   `firstname`,
   `user`.`lastname` as `lastname`,
   `user`.`lang` as `lang`,
   `user`.`name` as `user_name`,
   `group`.`name` as `group_name`
from `user`
  inner join `user_groups` on (`user`.`user_id`=`user_groups`.`user_id`)
  left  join `group` on (`group`.`group_id`=`user_groups`.`group_id`)
where `user`.`lang`=`group`.`lang`
```

This query creates a table that contains `firstname`, `lastname`, `lang`, `username`, `group_name` columns. I want it to also have an `id` column that is an autoincrement primary key.

Is there any way to do this by changing this query? 
I know I can do that by altering table after executing this query, but if there is any way to do this directly in the `create table` statement, I'd like to know how to do that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `user_mv` (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) SELECT `user`.`firstname` as 
   `firstname`,
   `user`.`lastname` as `lastname`,
   `user`.`lang` as `lang`,
   `user`.`name` as `user_name`,
   `group`.`name` as `group_name`
from `user`
  inner join `user_groups` on (`user`.`user_id`=`user_groups`.`user_id`)
  left  join `group` on (`group`.`group_id`=`user_groups`.`group_id`)
where `user`.`lang`=`group`.`lang`;
```

As long as you don't have an 'id' column in your `SELECT`, this appears to do exactly what you want.  The columns in the select will be appended to the right of the columns you declare.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html (also in previous versions).